# Create endpoint in Swagger to validate JWT token

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an API developed in .NET 5.0 in which I implemented Swagger.

Right now I have a endpoint in which the user obtain a JWT Token with a user and password and this token is used to authorize into swagger like below:

Authorize

[image]

Everything works fine to this point.

But now I want to implement and endpoint in which the user has to introduce this token to authorize swagger in order to use the API.

It is possible have these two validation? I want the user authorize through the button if they use the website but if they use postman (or another API) have to use the authorize endpoint.

I have searched to try this implementation and I found IOperationFilter but I'm not sure if its what I need

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear idea about this, but if I understand what you want to do correctly, you want to remove the security measures in requests made through the website.

While doing this, you can create a public token or define a guest or similar role and perform the transactions that occur on the website as if you are playing this guest role.

But finally, I must say that your request will cause a major security vulnerability. Also, keep in mind that every transaction performed on the website can be easily imitated by tools such as postman. This will completely override your other security measures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I didnt explain correctly.

Comment: The user can obtain a token through an endpoint and validate it using the authorize button in swagger, but I have to create an endpoint that allow the user to validate the token for using my API in postman.

Something like this:
* USER OBTAIN THE TOKEN BY AN ENDPOINT
* USER CALL ANOTHER ENDPOINT TO VALIDATE THIS TOKEN AND AUTHORIZE IN SWAGGER